# Matlab if loop not working

Tags: matlab, loops

```
%function [flag] =verify(area)

[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex]= uigetfile('*.tif','Select the signature file');
display(PathName) 
m=[PathName,FileName];
area=nor_area(m);
%display(area)

%area=0.8707;
class(area)

flag=0;
extract=xlsread('D:\Project\Image_processing\important\best.xlsx', 'CW4:CW17');
c=numel(extract);
display(c)
l=extract(1);
class(l)
display(l)
for k = 1:c
%x=extract(k);
if (l==area && flag==0)
     % display(extract(k)); 
      flag=1;
      display(flag)
end 
end
display(flag)
```

The above is my code for verification, i am not able to compare "l==area", even if the values are same am not able to enter inside the loop. If i try passing the value assume l=0.9999 and the area that i obtain to be the same , if i sent l value explicitly it works..!! but if i try using some function and pass the same value it wont work. I have tried checking the type by using class, both returns double.

Can anyone please help me out with this and if this approach is not good, suggest any alternative that may be used.

Comment: Perhaps the values are not the same.  Try printing `(l - area)`.

Comment: THe value is around is very small and its not equal to 0

Answer (score 3):

It is not generally a good idea to compare floats like you are doing (with the `==` operator) since floats, unlike integer values are subject to round off. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/22846/8/content/matlab_xunit_3.0/doc/html/exTolerance.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/66553) for a discussion on comparing floats in MATLAB.

Essentially you have to check that two floats are 'close enough' rather than exactly equal, which is what `==` checks for. MATLAB has a built in function `eps` for determining the floating point precision on your machine, so use that function when comparing floats. See its [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) for more information.

Comment: Is eps like a ceiling function. I couldnt figure out, how exactly it works.

I tried taking the difference of both area and l and then apply eps function, but if gives some e power values.

Comment: [`eps(x)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) returns the distance from `x` to the next largest floating point number, i.e. it is the step size between floats. Try `if abs(area-x) < eps(area)`.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it is not wise to compare floating point numbers by `a == b`. Use `abs(a-b)<epsilon` where `epsilon`is some small tolerance like `1e-10` instead.

Comment: MATLAB has a built in function [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html), which could be used instead of hard coding a tolerance.

Comment: if (abs(area-x)<eps && flag==0)     

i tried with this, but still the flag is zero

Comment: Try `abs(area-x) < eps(x)`. Does this return true? If the calculation of area is not accurate to double precision then this will return false (if it is accurate to single precision then use `eps('single')` instead of `eps(x)`). If you know how accurately you want to compare two floats then use @Boris' answer and set a small tolerance value, rather than use `eps`.

Comment: @Aps18 edit to my above comment: try `eps(single(x))`, rather than `eps('single')`

Comment: abs(area-x) < eps(x) I used this , its returning false. Its of double precision, i had found the class(area), it returns double. Both area and x are in double precision , but the problem here is x is of the form 0.8034(as its stored like that in the excel sheet), and area is of the form 0.080344444444..... as its calculated using the function in matlab. If there is anyway to truncate upto 4 decimal precision, i think that will make it work. Right?

Comment: @Aps18 You can use my proposal in this case by setting a rather loose tolerance, e.g., epsilon = 1e-4.

Comment: @Boris, The problem with mine is i cant set a threshold, as the area that i obtain is completely dynamic.

Comment: @Aps18 Then how do you know that the same area is meant?

Comment: @Boris, that is stored in excel sheet and that is compared with the area i get from a function, And both are checked.

Comment: Boris and Chris, Thank you for your help, it worked by using the loose threshold value :)